# Reset data quick links in branch.io

Tags: reset, deep-linking, branch.io

how do i reset clicks and other data from link in branch.io?
I have tried making a new one to get fresh data with the same settings, but i find that time consuming since it keep using new link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amruta from [branch.io](https://branch.io/) here:

Analytics software rarely allows you to directly modify historical data, so there is no way to completely DELETE the clicks/installs and other analytics data on the Branch dashboard. This could lead to corrupted or inaccurate data.

If you think the data associated with a link is no longer valid, you can either create new links to track fresh events or filter the analytics associated with the links by selecting the appropriate date range on the Branch dashboard.